# Why is this an incorrect solution to "Find how many $4$-digit numbers are divisible by $5$."?

Tags: combinatorics

**Problem: Find how many 4-digit numbers are divisible by 5.**

I started from two facts:

1. The number divisible by 5 ends with either 0 or 5.
2. The 4-digit number can't start with 0.

Then I calculated how many permutations end with 5 or 0: since there are 4 placeholders, if I put in the last one 0 or 5, there are three left to be filled with any digit, therefore $2 \cdot 10^3=2000$ (I multiplied by two because if the number ends in either $0$ or $5$, there are $3$ placeholders in case of both $0$ and $5$).

So, there are in total $2000$ permutations that end in $0$ or $5$.

Then I calculated how many of them start with 0: since, if we put 0 in the first place, there are 3 placeholders left, and each of them can hold up to 10 digits, and we arrive at the conclusion that there are $10^3=1000$ permutations that start with $0$.

Then I subtracted from the number of permutations that end in $0$ or $5$ the number of permutations that start with $0$: $2000-1000=1000$.

And then I concluded that there $1000$ $4$-digit numbers that are divisible by $5$.

---

But the solution is actually $1800$, which is arrived at like this: $9 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 \cdot 2=1800$. $9 \cdot 10 \cdot 10$ comes from that that when the last placeholder is filled, there are three placeholders left, each of which can be filled with any of the $10$ digits, except the first one that can't contain $0$. It is multiplied by two for both cases: $5$ in the last placeholder or $0$ in the last placeholder.

---

Why is the way that I tried incorrect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Then I calculated how many of them start with 0: since, if we put 0 in the first place, there are 3 placeholders left, and each of them can hold up to 10 digits, and we arrive at the conclusion that there are $10^3=1000$ permutations that start with 0.

Here is your mistake: you use the 'them' to refer to the $2000$ strings that end in a $0$ or $5$, but you proceeded to calculate the number of $4$ digit strings out of *all* $10,000$ digit strings that start with a $0$.

To see how many out of the $2,000$ ending with a $0$ or $5$ start with a $0$: given that they end with a $0$ or $5$, you only have $2$ possibilities for that last digit, and $10^2$ for the other two, making a total of $200$ out of those $2000$ that start with a $0$

Answer (score 5):

The number of numbers starting with $0$ is not $10^3$. It is $10\cdot10\cdot2$. You should only subtract out the numbers starting with $0$ which are divisible by $5$, so there are only two choices for the last digit.

Answer (score 0):

Consider four digit numbers: $0000-9999$.

Numbers ending with $0$:
$$***0 \Rightarrow n=10^3=1000.$$
Numbers ending with $5$:
$$***5 \Rightarrow n=10^3=1000.$$
So numbers ending with $0$ or $5$ is $2000$.

Numbers starting with $0$ and ending with $0$:
$$0**0 \Rightarrow n=10^2=100.$$
Numbers starting with $0$ and ending with $5$:
$$0**5 \Rightarrow n=10^2=100.$$
So numbers starting with $0$ and ending with $0$ or $5$ is $200$.

Hence, $2000-200=1800$.

Comment: Genuine question, why is everyone doing this via subtracting compensate for leading 0’s; is (9)(10)(10)(2) = 1800 not the most simple approach

Comment: I recant, OP’s explicit question was for why it is wrong! Sorry